# How to discuss attitude in team affecting performance?

Tags: professionalism, communication, management

Background: My manager wants me to bring a problem to him before my extended probation review. There has been an issue with communicating to the team lead. I have seen him onboard another hire as the same position as me very differently than me, for me it was like

> "why, why don't you understand this. It is right there"

kind of attitude. (basically, when I saw his onboarding another dev, I was shocked)

Today while on a group call, I asked my TL who was leading the call that if the scrum board jobs will have more detail on them besides the heading to which he replies was "what you mean"? and I explained if there will be more detail to which he said yes, after the call I asked

> if we are going to start sprint 0 today or tomorrow

Another developer replied today, and the Team Leader asked if "we are all clear what are we doing" to which I said no.(I was being honest) His reply in the group chat was

> Really? Did u even listen to what we said, why didn't you say you didn't understand in the call?
> and I did while we were on call

so he pasted me what we are doing today and tomorrow in a rude manner(IMO)

> Ok, Flux.
> Today, 24 September - we are researching on this. Tomorrow,
> 25 September - we are researching on this. Did you understand? if you
> DID NOT UNDERSTAND speak
>
> Are you sure?

While on the call He said if I understood and not? don't ask help later in the afternoon.

He made it sound like I sit idle and do no work, or confused (mind you he want to make a ticket as he sees fit and doesn't bother about explaining more)

I feel his behavior is insulting as he has issue with everything, e.g. "Flux there is alarm beeping in your background, can u take out batteries", "can you speak up", "can you", "can you" etc. I saw the same pattern with another developer who said "Flux has a lot of background and I cannot hear anything" where there wasn't anyone in the house.

How do I discuss with my manager in my 1-2-1 because:

1. I am on extended probation (and the manager wants me to bring the issues even related to comms before the final review)
2. My mind has totally blocked and I feel demotivated for work and listening because of my treatment on the team

P.S. - I am on the verge of quitting my job because of the behavior

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a matter of miscommunication.

> the Team Leader asked if "we are all clear what are we doing"

He asked if it was clear **what** you are doing. And you do know that: you'll be working on that ticket which you described as needing more information.

> to which I said no.(I was being honest)

You're responding that you don't know all the details of that ticket, but that's not the question that was asked. You know *what* you will be doing, you just don't know exactly how you'll resolve it yet.

Handling the ticket can include requesting more information. That doesn't mean you're not handling the ticket, it just means that you're not *solving* the issue yet, instead researching the issue (either by means of communication or investigation).

So when you said "no", your TL presumably understood that you did not even know which ticket you'd be handling. That is not what you intended to say, but it is what you ended up saying (from the TL's point of view)

> "Really? Did u even listen to what we said, why didn't you say you didn't understand in the call?"

> Is this behavior insulting as I felt like it?

Regardless, this response comes across as unprofessional and needlessly aggressive.

But this is probably not an isolated event. Maybe this TL is always aggressive off the bat. Maybe this is the culmination of struggling to communicate effectively, or having a hard time planning a sprint with unclear tickets. Maybe this isn't the first time you're responding to a different question than was asked.

I'm not willing to immediately condemn the TL as irredeemably aggressive, I don't have the full picture. Their communication should be tempered more than it currently is, but I cannot judge the full picture here if there are external factors that have pushed this TL to the end of their rope.

> How do I discuss with my manager who been telling me off that he will book time but it is the third week there is no booked time?

This is a completely different issue. If a ticket is assigned to you, you are expected to handle it, and the ticket does not contain sufficient information for you to handle, then the ticket needs to be put on hold (after requesting the needed information).

Whether time is booked on that ticket while it is on hold is a matter of agreement between customer and company.

There have been cases in my career (in multiple companies) where a customer has asked for priority treatment of a ticket and agreed to be billed for "on hold" time as well if it meant that we would always immediately pick up that ticket again when the information was added.

On the other hand, it might be that tickets on hold are not billed (this is the most common approach), but then you talk to your TL and ask what you should be working on while this ticket is on hold.

If the TL (or your company) fails to assign work to you when you have no work, **that is not your fault**. It's the company's responsibility to assign work to you.

This does of course assume that the ticket you put on hold was correctly put on hold because you could not work on it yet. If you put tickets on hold that you could've worked on, even if less efficiently than if you had had all the needed details, then you can rightly be blamed for deferring assigned work duties - intentionally or not.

Comment: I have edited the question and add more detail and cut out rant

Comment: *But this is probably not an isolated event. Maybe this TL is always aggressive off the bat. Maybe this is the culmination of struggling to communicate effectively, or having a hard time planning a sprint with unclear tickets. Maybe this isn't the first time you're responding to a different question than was asked.* he has a different attitude towards the team and towards me, it might be I am Asian and others are native British or maybe he wants to pick up breadcrumbs.

Comment: Yes, it may ALSO be you have shown a history of being complicated to work with and super sensitive. Do not attribute something to racism that may easily be your performance. WAY easier to say it is racism instead of looking into the mirror.

Comment: @flux: Based on the posted interaction, it seems you are prone to misunderstanding an asked question and answering something different from what was asked. If that consistently happens (which _you_ can't reliably disprove, since your observation is biased in cases where you unknowingly misunderstood something), that is going to significantly impact how people respond to this repeated behavior from you. I can't for a fact state that this is the case, but it is definitely one of the _possible_ cases I'm considering here as a mitigating factor for the team lead's response.